# How to Join two tables with the join being regexp_replace

Tags: oracle, join

Need your help, I have two tables “temp” and “temp 1”

The temp table I am deriving a column called numbers. I am
wondering how do you join table temp1 onto temp and joint on

```
SELECT regexp_replace(indicator,'[^0-9]') as Numbers
from temp

Select Number 
From temp2
```

I tried the following however it’s not recognised

```
SELECT indicator,
       regexp_replace(indicator,'[^0-9]') as numbers
from temp
Left join temp2 
    on temp.number= temp2.numbers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly use the `alias` in `ON` clause or in `WHERE` condition

So simply use your expression in `ON` clause:

```
SELECT t.indicator,
       regexp_replace(t.indicator,'[^0-9]') as numbers
from temp t
Left join temp2 t2
    on (regexp_replace(t.indicator,'[^0-9]') = t2.<Join column name>);
```

Cheers!!